# Excel - Copy row from another sheet based on lookup value

Tags: excel

I have two excel sheets -- sheet 1 and sheet 2.

Sheet 1

[image]

Sheet 2

[image]

The user data is split between the two sheets. Each user is identified by a unique ID which is present in a column in both sheets.

I need to search for each ID from sheet 1 in sheet 2. If the ID exists in sheet 2, I need to copy the data of the entire row from sheet 2 to sheet 1 and paste it in the same row as the ID.

Result should be Updated Sheet 1

[image]

I am able to use VLOOKUP to copy data one row at a time, but that would not be feasible for the actual data, and I do not know how to use vba. Is there any way to do it using VLOOKUP or some other commands?

Comment: Are you replacing data in Sheet1, or rather, just adding columns? If the latter, then why is VLOOKUP too hard? You just need create the correct formulas once per column and then drag them down.

Comment: @Isolated Adding columns, not replacing. There are more than 100 columns.

Comment: Ok. Is this a 1-time event? If so, properly sorting with aid of a helper column and then copy/paste would just take a minute.

Comment: @Isolated Not a one time event. Also, IDs in sheet 2 will be a subset of IDs in sheet 1. Sorting will lead to mismatch.

Comment: I think adding some sample data from both sheets would be helpful to solve. Not sure if this would work for you, but within a vlookup formula, could you cheat by using `COLUMN()` as the column_index_number? That would only work if the column numbers are precisely where you need them. That would avoid the need the change the reference each time.

Comment: @Isolated Added images. Tried COLUMN, INDEX, MATCH, IFERROR and various combinations. Couldn't get it to work. Can you please post a full answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your sample data, you could cheat in your vlookup formula by using the COLUMN() function as your column_index_number. This will save you the time needed to make 100 replacements.

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($A4,Sheet2!$A:$C,COLUMN()-2,FALSE),"")
```

Or better yet, this will prevent 0's if you have some columns w/out information but the ID is found:

```
=IFERROR(IF(LEN(VLOOKUP($A4,Sheet2!$A:$C,COLUMN()-2,FALSE))=0,"",VLOOKUP($A4,Sheet2!$A:$C,COLUMN()-2,FALSE)),"")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This seems to be exactly what I need. I haven't been able to get it to work on the main data yet. Can you please tell me what is the purpose of the -2? Also, does ID have to be the first column for this solution to work?

Comment: The -2 depends on how many columns you have to the left of it. If you have 26 columns between the ID and the first column you're adding, then you'll need -26. You'll see what I mean by just typing `=COLUMN()` in a cell. It returns a number. ID needs to be to the left of whatever you're looking up, that's all.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that you need VBA.  You could use it, but using VLOOKUP is easier.

For example, let's say you have a column of IDs in Sheet1 in column A.  You have a bunch of data in Sheet2 where you have IDs in Column A in rows 2-100, and six pieces of data in columns B-G.  You want to copy those to cells B-G on Sheet 1.

Then the easiest thing to do is in cell Sheet1!B2 use the formula =VLOOKUP(A2, Sheet2!A$2:B$100,2,0).  In cell Sheet1!C2 use the formula = VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet2!A$2:C$100,3,0), and so on.  For each cell increase the width of the range that you are looking in and the number of the column.

Do the other four as well to populate the entirety of row 2.  Then copy the contents of cells B-G for the length of the data in column A.

It's important when you do this to use $ in the cell references for Sheet2.  If you don't, then when you copy your formulas to row 3 you will be looking in the range A3:B101.  The dollar sign before the row number means that as you copy those formulas from row to row on Sheet1 the rows of the range on Sheet2 will not change.

---

Having said that, when I started using VBA, the first thing I would do is record a macro doing what I wanted to do once.  I would look at the macro and see what I could modify.

For example, let's say your first record ID on Sheet1 is in cell A2.  When you are done with the processing, you will need to go look at the record in cell A3.  Your macro will record this as something like Range("A3").Select, but you need something more generic, so you will go to the next cell down, whatever it is.  You can do that with Selection.Offset(1,0).Select, which means "go one cell down," or you can assign your row to a variable like MyRow, increment it with MyRow = MyRow + 1, and then do Range("A" + MyRow).Select.

Anything you have to do more than once you will want to put in a loop.  I would usually start by going to the very bottom of the spreadsheet and then selecting upward to find the last row with data in it.  You can make your loop stop when it encounters a blank line, but what if someone left a blank line on your sheet and you need to skip that one and continue processing?

Comment: Thanks for your response! For my particular problem, the answer posted by Isolated is more suitable.